# Не запускается приложение kivy, упакованное с помощью PyInstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Простой работающий myapp.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        Al = AnchorLayout()
        Gl = GridLayout(rows=1, padding=30)
        Gl.add_widget(Button(text="Подключиться"))
        Al.add_widget(Gl)
        return Al


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Скомпилирован через PyInstaller через myapp.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['myapp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='myapp',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='myapp')
```

При запуске myapp.exe выдаёт ошибку:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\Username\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-04-30_7.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.1
[INFO   ] Python: v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] Text: Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура.
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] App: Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Не помогло:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew  
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer  
pip install kivy.deps.angle  
pip install –-upgrade kivy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
python -m pip install pyenchant
python -m pip install cython
python -m pip install Pillow
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы минимально прокомментировать своё решение и объснить в чем его суть или же в чем была ошибка TC

Answer (score 0):

В этом видео все подробно описано - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bK5JJFVMbk&t=68s